# No $_GET = empty($_GET)?

Tags: php, session, get, pagination

I have a paginated table of names and ages that I want to filter by the "name" field.
For that I have an input called "name".

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">
```

While switching between pages, in order to not carry around the filter in the url in the form of:

```
table.php?name=John&page=3
```

i am saving the $_GET['name'] to a $_SESSION['name'] and then apply that session to the SQL query string.

```
$_GET['name'] ? $_SESSION['name']=$_GET['name'] : null;
```

I would like to be able to clear the filter by having the user deleting the content from the input and pressing enter.
I have tried:

```
if($_GET['name']=="")
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

The problem is that when I switch page and use the link:

```
table.php?page=7
```

it resets $_SESSION['name'] and takes me back to the selected page of the unfiltered table.

Any ideas on how I can work around this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of unsetting `$_SESSION['name']` have you tried setting it to the blank value?

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: What is setting the session in that page?

Comment: Your ternary operation  is abnormal
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'] ? $_GET['name'] : null;

Comment: Its not really clear from your question what the order of event will be when you want to remove the name from the session. Can you make your question more clear please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue by repacing

```
if($_GET['name']=="")
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

with

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) and $_GET['name']=="")
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

the isset() made all the difference.
Now it will properly check if an empty value is being passed in the $_GET['name'] and proceed with the IF accordingly.

Many thanks all of you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in your ternary operation. At first dont use this operation if you don't understand his logic. Ternary operation can reduce the amount of code, but in the same time can confuse you very much.
So:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'] ? $_GET['name'] : null;
```

Comment: It mght well be better to do `$_SESSION['name'] = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : null;` assuming of course you want NULL to be the default value

Comment: It's right. But if we are talking about the checks like isset(), then data from $_GET need to check better :)
@Emanuel Pacheco Pontes Did we answer on your question?

Comment: Well as he was not asking about the ternary operator, i would guess, no you have not!

Comment: My ternary operation is meant to replace isset($_GET['name']).
which if evaluates to true, stores the get value in the session, else does nothing.
Basically it will check if a value is being passed in the get, if it is, it uses it, if it isn't it does nothing.

Comment: Basically it will check if a value is being passed in the get, if it is, it uses it, if it isn't it does nothing.
My intent is not to check if the GET is equal to the SESSION.and then proceed.
My intent is to check if a value is being passed by GET, and if it is, store it in session.
But my issue is that the IF is unsetting the SESSION even tho there is no ?name=foo in the url.